# Embed reactively generated URL in shiny

Tags: r, url, shiny

I would like to show in my shiny app a link that directs to the URL generated based on user's input. I don't want to show the full text of the URL. I know the a(href="",label="") function can be used if I know the URL beforehand, but in this case the URL depends on the user's input. The following doesn't work:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Show map of a given state"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            textInput("state", label = "State", value = "CA", placeholder = "California or CA"),
            actionButton("showU","Show map")
        ),
        mainPanel(
            conditionalPanel(
                condition = "input.showU > 0",
                htmlOutput("url"),
                a(href=htmlOutput("url"),"Show in Google Map",target="_blank")
            )
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output){
    observeEvent(input$showU,{
    output$url <-renderUI({paste("https://www.google.com/maps/place/", input$state, sep="")})
    })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

I hope I can click on the "Show in Google Map" and be directed to the URL generated on the fly. Please help me, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `renderUI` together with `uiOutput` to update UI reactively:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Show map of a given state"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("state", label = "State", value = "CA", placeholder = "California or CA"),
      actionButton("showU","Show map")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.showU > 0",
        uiOutput("url")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  observeEvent(input$showU,{
    output$url <-renderUI(a(href=paste0('https://www.google.com/maps/place/', input$state),"Show in Google Map",target="_blank"))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @YuZhang glad my answer helped, please accept it then

Answer (score 0):

If this questions is actually about creating reactive URL links, then HubertL's answer is the way to go.

If you want to keep the map and search funciton all self-contained in the shiny, rather than having to open a new link to Google Maps, you can use my [`googleway`](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway) package to achieve the same task

```
library(shiny)
library(googleway)


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Show map of a given state"),
  sidebarLayout(
     sidebarPanel(
     ),
    mainPanel(
      google_mapOutput(outputId = "myMap", height = "600px")

    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){

  ## you need a valid API key from Google Maps
  ## https://developers.google.com/maps/

  map_key <- "your_map_api_key"

  output$myMap <- renderGoogle_map({
    google_map(key = map_key, search_box = T)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

[image]

Comment: This is really cool! I installed from github `devtools::install_github("SymbolixAU/googleway")`.

Comment: @YuZhang - glad you like it. Note it's still in development so may change slightly, but should be stable for general use

Comment: @YuZhang - Note the map widget is now on CRAN, there's no more need for the development version

Answer (score 0):

I used a HTML button for which the url could be generated recursively

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("HTML button"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         sliderInput("bins",
                     "Number of bins:",
                     min = 1,
                     max = 50,
                     value = 30)
      ),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot"),
         HTML(paste0(htmlOutput('url_test')))
      )
   )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
      x    <- faithful[, 2] 
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

      # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
   })

   output$url_test = renderText({
     paste('<a href=',cultivar_url(),' class="btn btn-default">Go to Google</a>')
   })

   cultivar_url = reactive({
     print('https://www.google.com')
   }) 
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```